# Rectangle is not drawed properly?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Hello i want to draw rounded rectangle without any function, but first I tried to draw simple rectangle but it is not drawed properly. What is wrong ?

```
int main() 
{
    Mat frame = Mat::zeros(300,300,CV_8UC1);
    //frame = duzKare(50);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) //col
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) // row
        {
            frame.at<int>(i, j) = 255;
        }
    }

    //rounded_rect(30, 50);
    namedWindow("Demo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Demo", frame);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: this is my output]

Comment: Also as you can see, this code draw simple rectangle with cout<<"* ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `<u_char>` instead of `<int>` in `frame.at<int>(i, j) = 255;`
`CV_8UC1` means the value of each pixel is stored as an unsigned char (`u_char` in `OpenCV`) which is 8-bit while `int` occupies more than 8 bits

Comment: hey thank you man it was good hint, i use CV_32FC1 as channel type and use <float> in frame.at<float>(i, j) = 255;  and it works properly.